# get one key from nested document

Tags: c#, mongodb

i have a document like this one.

```
{ "_id": { "$oid" : "517e3fccc9c02d22c85f3a6f" }, 
"skillData": [ { "skillID": 3001, 
"level": 1 }, { "skillID": 3002, 
"level": 1 }, { "skillID": 1, 
"level": 1 }, { "skillID": 2, 
"level": 1 }, { "skillID": 3, 
"level": 1 } ], 
"username": "myID"}
```

what i want to do is get the skillID and store it on a variable for comparing to my own array
my code is like this

```
foreach (var item in rows)
{
    var skillData = (BsonArray)item["skillData"];//this is the array of the document

    Console.WriteLine(skillData);
    int i=0;
    while(i < 5)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < skillData.Count; j++)
        {
            if (skillData[j] == equipTileArray[i])//this is where i want to compare
            {
                isSkillIDFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

but `skillData[j]` return me the whole document while I only want the `skillID` from the document. what should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it your document item `skillData` is an array of sub-documents, each of which contains values for `skillID` and `level`.  So you need to further parse those.  I'm not overly familiar with mongodb, but my guess would be that you need to either try referencing `skillData[j]["skillID"]` instead of `skillData[j]` or interpret each of the elements of `skillData` as a new [BsonDocument](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/3a31e174-4df4-91f3-6760-02078b53ddb1.htm)

Comment: as you can see on my code, does it saved as `(BsonArray)`? the `["skillID"]`?

Comment: Actually no, I can't see that.  Currently the only explicit cast to `BsonArray` happens before `item["skillData"]`

Comment: well I found my way to get that value by using this code,
`var skillIDs = skillData[j].AsBsonDocument.GetValue("skillID").ToString();`
so thanks for answering...

Comment: @Diom you might want to add that as your own answer, then, and mark it as the correct answer so no one else digs this up and tries to answer it.  You might even want to include a code sample of your solution in case anyone else comes looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem of mine is solved via using code like this

`var skillIDs = skillData[j].AsBsonDocument.GetValue("skillID").ToString();`

here is some example using some code i post here:

```
foreach (var item in rows)
{
    var skillData = (BsonArray)item["skillData"];//this is the array of the document

    Console.WriteLine(skillData);
    int i=0;
    while(i < 5)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < skillData.Count; j++)
        {
            var skillIDs = skillData[j].AsBsonDocument.GetValue("skillID").ToString();
            if (skillIDs == equipTileArray[i])
            {
                isSkillIDFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Thats All.